# How to tak password in hidden fromat in CLI mode

Tags: install4j

I am working on Installer for CentOS7 platform and i want to take password input from user in similar format like the linux password i.e hidden mode for CLI implementation.
Is there is any way to take password input in hidden format in CLI mode console handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
String password = console.askPassword("Prompt", "default value");
```

in a console handler form component or in any script where the console parameter is available.